# npx cap sync vs npx cap copy

Tags: angularjs, capacitor

I am new to the capacitor and developing an application where I am making changes into code and running

1. ionic build
2. npx cap copy
3. npx cap open android

And it is also recommended to use `npx cap sync` in behalf of `npx cap copy`.
What is the exactly difference between both.
where to use which one ? Please assist.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`npx cap copy` just copies whatever is in your `webDir` to the native platforms (and some cordova files if you have cordova plugins installed).

`npx cap sync` runs `npx cap copy` and `npx cap update`

`npx cap update` searches for Cordova and Capacitor plugins and copy/update some native files the plugins need for working.

So copy is for "web" files and update for "native" files and sync does both.